# Javascript String escape character

Tags: javascript, string

Hi I have javascript string like this: 
`let a = "\"2\" Kilogram"`.

I want it to look like this  `a = "2 Kilogram"`.

I have used `unescape` and `str.replace` but the response is like `" "2" Kilogram"`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = "\"2\" Kilogram";
a = a.replace(/\"/g, "");
console.log(a);
```

Replacing using regex will help you here as a pro.

`\"` is to be replaced and `g` is used as global iterator which will return only once all possibilities have been replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the double quote like:

```
a = a.replace(/"/g, '')
```

**Demo:**

```js
let a = "\"2\" Kilogram"

console.log("Before:", a)
a = a.replace(/"/g, '')
console.log("After:", a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let a = "\"2\" Kilogram";
 console.log(a.replace(/"/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to replace `\"` like below

```js
let a = "\"2\" Kilogram"

a = a.replace(/\"/g, "")

console.log(a)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you generelly want to remove all kind of special characters of the English language in a `string` and not only `""` you may use:

```js
    let string2replace = "\"2\" Kilogram";
    var desiredstring = string2replace.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
    alert(desiredstring);
```

Answer (score -1):

`a = a.slice(0, 2)+a.slice(3, a.length)+'"';`

Or just use single quotes so the inner double quotes are not interpolated when you set the value `a` in the first place ;)

`let a ='"2 Kilogram";'`